# How to download files from Facebook group?

Tags: facebook-groups, bulk-download

I'd like to download Files hosted on Facebook group which I'm part of.

I couldn't find any relevant API, and the following [question at Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-download-all-file-uploaded-to-a-Facebook-group-easily) points to extensions which are outdated.

The first challenge is to click on *See more* to see all the files, then click them one by one. Sometimes after *See more*, the AJAX loading is stuck, so the whole page needs to be refresh and started again.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps can be used:

1. Navigate to *Files* page on *Facebook* using your web-browser.
2. Using [*DevTools*](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) JS Console in web-browser, run the following code (ignore the red *Stop* sign):

   ```
   setInterval(function() { document.getElementsByClassName("uiMorePagerPrimary")[0].click(); }, 20000);
   ```

   The script is going to click *See more* button every 20 seconds, even when it's stuck.
3. When page is fully loaded, extract all links into `urls` variable.

   ```
   var urls = [];
   for (var i = document.links.length; i --> 0;) if (document.links[i].href.includes("download")) urls.push(document.links[i].href);
   ```

   <sup>Source: [How to get all the URLs in a web site using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3824208/55075)</sup>
4. Optionally you can print the links using `console.log(urls)` or `console.table(urls)`.
5. Copy the links to clipboard by running: `copy(urls.join("\n"))` and paste into the text file.
6. From the *Network* tab of *DevTools*, pick one request and *Copy as cURL* (not *all*).
7. Convert into `wget` by making the following adjustments to the command (as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204327/55075)):

   - Change `curl` to `wget` (1st string from the left).
   - Remove the URL (2nd string from the left).
   - Remove `--compress` parameter.
   - Change `-H` to `--header` in all places.
   - Add `-nc` or `-c` to not re-download the existing files.
   - Add `--content-disposition` parameter.
   - Point to the text file with the list by adding: `-i list.txt`.

   <sub>Note: If you're Vim user, run `set -o vi`, type command, and hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, to edit shell command in Vim.</sub>
8. Run above converted command, to start downloading the files. It should looks like:

   ```
   wget --header '...' --header '...' --content-disposition -c -i list.txt
   ```